# Does "fork out" only mean "pay unwillingly"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I was wondering if I could use the word "**fork out**" in the following context, implying that a person doesn't wish to spend a lot of money.

*If you don't feel like **forking out**, we could go to a cheaper joint*.

Or is this word only used to emphasize reluctancy? Which word could you use to replace it, then, in order to communicate the above-said properly?

Thanks.

Comment: [**Splurge**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/splurge) *- to spend (money) lavishly or ostentatiously*. Although idiomatic *fork out* usually implies reluctance, it doesn't have to.

Comment: I'm sorry but you never said if my sentence was correct or not.

Comment: This site (ELU) is for [linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Proofreading is Off Topic anyway, but if you're asking for help on basic vocabulary/grammar, you should be using [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: My question concerns the usage of the word "fork out". I asked if I used it correctly. Some are too snobbish on this site. Thanks for nothing.

Comment: I'm not being "snobbish". I'm simply pointing out that this is the wrong site for your question. I'll even address your Off Topic proofreading request (it's grammatically fine) - but if you're going to ask further questions like this, it's better that you know *now* where to go next time.

Comment: I didn't ask for proofreading. I only asked if the word I'd used was good for the context. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22feel+like+forking+out%22) are a couple of dozen written instances of *feel like forking out*, which I'm sure will all match your cited context. But as I said originally, although it often implies paying *reluctantly*, that implication doesn't *have* to be present. You should also note that the usage is relatively informal, so it won't be suitable in all contexts.

Comment: I think "grudgingly" would be a more apt adverb than "unwillingly".

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, in idiomatic English I maintain that if the sentence (or fragment of a sentence ) is successful in conveying the intended meaning, it is allowed.  It may not be grammatically proper, but languages evolve.

I will not attest to the etymology of 'fork out', but it *may* refer to the act of 'forking out' manure on a farm.  Both connote an undesirable task, but as mentioned above, 'fork out '  when purchasing is not necessarily negative or reluctant, but may be the result of colorful, local slang.